# how to write codes using django

Tags: python, django, eclipse, django-templates, django-admin

how to write python codes in ubuntu platform using django framework. Also is it possible to use django in windows platform for writing python codes? Can django be used with eclipse(i have PyDev pluging in my eclipse IDE).Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? There are decent Django tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how to write python codes in ubuntu platform using django framework.

Open a text editor and write the code.

> Also is it possible to use django in windows platform for writing
>   python codes?

Yes

> Can django be used with eclipse(i have PyDev pluging in my eclipse
>   IDE)

Yes